# How make an php file to be able for Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using CodeIgniter, and i have some issues with AJAX, to be honest it's my first time using it. So some questions are growing.

What I need:

I need post using AJAX and getting id.

The content:

```
    <div class="the-game" id="3">
    <div class="center">
    <input type="text" id="team_1" class="field">
    <span> X </span>
    <input type="text" id="team_2" class="field">
    </div>
    <input type="text" style="display:block;" maxlength="2" class="multi" value="1" id="number_times">
    <a href="#" class="action">GO</a>

<a href="#" id="show_guesses">show guesses</a>
<div class="guesses">

THIS DIV RECEIVE GUESSES WHEN PAGE LOAD, USING PHP.
<ul>
<li>

    <input type="text" id="team_1" class="field" value="2">
    <span> X </span>
    <input type="text" id="team_2" class="field" value="3">
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
    </div>

<!-- OTHER GAME -->

    <div class="the-game" id="4">
    <div class="center">
    <input type="text" id="team_1" class="field">
    <span> X </span>
    <input type="text" id="team_2" class="field">
    </div>
    <input type="text" style="display:block;" maxlength="2" class="multi" value="1" id="number_times">
    <a href="#" class="action">GO</a>
<a href="#" id="show_guesses">show guesses</a>
<div class="guesses">

THIS DIV RECEIVE GUESSES WHEN PAGE LOAD, USING PHP.
<ul>
<li>

    <input type="text" id="team_1" class="field" value="2">
    <span> X </span>
    <input type="text" id="team_2" class="field" value="3">
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
    </div>
```

Ok, im already getting id from `class="the-game"` using `parent()` function. Now i want understand how do i post in my php file, its already support

```
$id_game, $team_1, $team_2.
```

So i need post:

```
$id_game, $team_1, $team_2
```

into `/salve_guess` using Ajax by pressing `a class="action"`.

My javascript at moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$('.guesses').hide();
$( "#the-game input" ).click(function() {
var id = ($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id"));

$(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.guesses').slideToggle(360, 'swing');


});
$( "a#show_guesses" ).click(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().next('.guesses').slideToggle(360, 'swing');
});
});
```

Now the critical part:

I want know how do make the PHP return if its failed or its success and send it to AJAX and AJAX show it to user calling an alert or a pop up. Can I use any function to JavaScript see the content of HTML written by PHP file? And the most difficult part to me, it can be done more than 1 time, like 20 times per 1 action (an for each in PHP).

And I want show this new guess in the page without reload it (remember I'm already show the guesses using PHP, so I need just insert this new guess called by `a="action"` and insert in top of this div `class=guesses` and need use the id, so the PHP can write an list of ids and jQuery get it and rescribe HTML using this ids from PHP file?

Sorry, for be too long, but I'm stuck at this point.

Hope you guys understand.

Your sincerely.

Comment: can you put your javascript above?

Comment: You need to read a few ajax tutorials [Using jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) or [Using just javascript](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxphp.php) and search for a few other

Comment: @Vainglory07 atm its a simple javascript just to show and get id, i want someone show me the way to do it.

Comment: just to clarify, you want to get the input value of `#team_1`, `#team_2` when `GO` is pressed and pass it in your CI controller as `$team_1 = #team_1` and `$team_2 = #team_2` and get the return of that controller back to your javascript?

Comment: @Vainglory07 Exactly what I need, but its can be done more than 1 time, because  <input type="text" style="display:block;" maxlength="2" class="multi" value="1" id="number_times"> #number_times said how many times i need do it, like for each, then its save as a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding :):
Let's say you have this markup (im confused with your mark up, just tell me if this is wrong):

```
<div class="the-game" id="3">
    <div class="center">
        <input type="text" id="team_1" class="field" value="2">
        <span> X </span>
        <input type="text" id="team_2" class="field" value="3">
    </div>

    <input type="text" style="display:block;" maxlength="2" class="multi" value="1" id="number_times">
    <a href="#" class="action">GO</a>
    <a href="#" id="show_guesses">Show Guesses</a>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Where

**id** in `<div class="the-game" id="3">` is your `id_game`,

**value** in `<input type="text" id="team_1" class="field" value="2">` is your `team_1`,

**value** in `<input type="text" id="team_2" class="field" value="3">` is your `team_2`,

**value** in `<input type="text" style="display:block;" maxlength="2" class="multi" value="1" id="number_times">` is your number of loop.

Then to get these in javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.action').on('click', function () {
            // Get game ID
            var get_id_game = $(this).parent('.the-game').attr('id');
            // Get team 1
            var get_team_1 = $('#team_1').val();
            // Get team 2
            var get_team_2 = $('#team_1').val();
            // Get loop count
            var get_multi = $('#number_times').val();

            $.post(
                'http://localhost/helpers/jquery/salve_guess.php', {
                    id_game: get_id_game,
                    team_1: get_team_1,
                    team_2: get_team_2,
                    multi: get_multi
                }, function (data) {
                    // data arg here will contain the output of your controller
                    // convert json string to json obj
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    var markup;
                    $.each(json, function (index, value) {

                        markup = [
                            '<div class="guesses">',
                                '<ul>',
                                    '<li class="guess" id="' + index + '">',
                                    value.id_game + '-' + value.team_1 + '-' + value.team_2,
                                    '</li>',
                                '</ul>',
                            '</div>',
                        ];

                        $('#output').append(markup.join('\n'));
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your controller you receive the post data like this (my way of doing it):

```
public function salve_guess() {
    $id_game = $this->input->post('id_game', TRUE);
    $team_1 = $this->input->post('team_1', TRUE);
    $team_2 = $this->input->post('team_2', TRUE);

    $json_arr = array(
        // incrementing ID => array(id_game, team_1, team_2)
        1 => array(
            'id_game' => 1, 
            'team_1' => 2, 
            'team_2' => 3
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id_game' => 1, 
            'team_1' => 2, 
            'team_2' => 3
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($json_arr);
}
```

Note: [$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: Ok its right, and now, how do i tell to ajax write this action done by controller and my javascript get the id from salve_guess controller and put into <div class="guesses"> <li class="guess" id="IDFROMCONTROLLER"></li></div>

Comment: Because im planing edit the guess without refresh page, so i need the id, and the id is auto increment generated from controller, i can print the array of ids and others values in controller and javascript ready it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: your controller will just return the ID then?

Comment: no, its return the value of input of team_1 and team_2 and the id_game

Comment: Because in list of guesses its ill be anything like this: id of li and inside this li two inputs the first one with the value of team_1 and the second input with value of team_2.

Comment: I dont need use loop in javascript, because im already telling it to controller, when i pass multi value the php use loop while and do this function.

Comment: Can i make an way to my controller return ids of guess in a  div contaning li class="id" (that ill print id of guess) and the values of inputs in li class="team_1", li class="team_2", and my javascript ready every <div> and return in my page as <div class="guesses"> <li class="guess" id="IDFROMCONTROLLER"></li></div> on top of list.

Comment: Or return as json array and ids come in id key, i dont know how do it. Thank you for your patient.

Comment: so you are passing the multi value alongside with team_1, team_2 and id_game?

Comment: i update my answer. its up to you now how your are going to generate the `$json_arr` as long as you follow the format i put above :D

Comment: Thank you! Really thank you! ill test and check if is working, if yes ill accept your answer

Comment: sure :D if have question just tell me

Comment: Thank you, im amazed how its works. If you got some time can look this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707483/two-inputs-using-slidetoggle-for-same-div