# Two inputs using slideToggle for same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is my html code:

```
 <div class="the-game" id="3">
    <div class="center">
    <input type="text" id="team_1" class="field">
    <span> X </span>
    <input type="text" id="team_2" class="field">
    </div>
    <input type="text" style="display:block;" maxlength="2" class="multi" value="1" id="number_times">
    <a href="#" class="action">GO</a>

<a href="#" id="show_guesses">show guesses</a>
<div class="guesses">
WHEN CLICK IN INPUT TOGGLE THIS DIV.
<ul>
<li>

    <input type="text" id="team_1" class="field" value="2">
    <span> X </span>
    <input type="text" id="team_2" class="field" value="3">
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#the-game input" ).click(function() {


$(this).parent().parent().parent().next('.guesses').slideToggle(360, 'swing');


});
```

Like i said, Have two inputs im not specifying the input that calls slideToggle, and have two that can do it, but i want:

When a user click on an input its toggle the div, but when click on the other input that inst clicked yet no toggle (before a time), if its takes alot of time its can toggle using the other input.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/KJm2K/

Comment: @pete Yeah, but when click on the second input that inst clicked yet it should NO toggle , just toggle after some time, otherwise div ill dance...hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding it hard to gather what it is you are wanting to achieve? Firstly your selector needs changing to select the correct element:

`$('#the-game input')` to `$('.the-game input')`

The following will do a toggle on your html input element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.the-game input', function () {
    $('.guesses').slideToggle(360, 'swing');
});
```

Can you provide more information around the second input field about what you want to do around it?

Comment: Both inputs toogle my div, so if i put any value in first field my div shows, and if i click on second input and put an value my div close...Both inputs are same, i can set any time to toggle again? like just 1 toggle per 4 seconds?